# How to return a cell range (e.g. A10:C20) from a named range in Excel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I need to know how to return a cell range (e.g. A10:C20) from a named range called "Items" in Excel using PowerShell. I would like to delete entries in the second column of "Items" (B10:B20). I tried using .RefersToLocal method to return the range but it doesn't return anything. I'm new to PowerShell. Thank you for your help.

```
    $Path = "C:\file.xls"

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $false
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Path) 
    $page = 'Main'
    $ws = $Workbook.worksheets | where-object {$_.Name -eq $page}

    $ws.Range("Items").RefersToLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use range directly and then use the column attribute of the range elements (2 for B column) to clear and save it, like this:

```
$Path = "i:\named.xls"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Path) 
$page = 'Main'
$ws = $Workbook.worksheets | where-object {$_.Name -eq $page}

$namedarea = $ws.Range("items")

$namedarea | ?{$_.column -eq 2} | %{$_.clear()}

$excel.Save()
```

Comment: What you have provided works, thank you! Is there a way to access the second column in the range and clear it without referencing the spreadsheet column letter (e.g B)? If someone moves the range to a different location in the spreadsheet I don't want to have to update the code if that happens. Users tend to do this sort of thing (move things around) without realizing the repercussion of what they have done :)

Comment: Also is there a way not to remove cell formats when clearing values in the column? I have the cells bordered in black and the cells colored. Thanks